# Bind random integer from list to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo `DropDownListFor` but I believe it's similar to how it's setup for .NET MVC native dropdownlists.

So I have something like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.QuestionID).HtmlAttributes())
```

Can I do something like this instead?

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(ListFromController.RandomlyGeneratedFirstInt).HtmlAttributes())
```

So that instead of binding a specific value from my viewmodel, I can bind an integer I can grab from the first slot in my list of ints that is being passed from my controller?

Or I was just thinking, in my controller action, I have my a list of random ints and I should just set the ints in my controller to specific properties in my viewmodel. That way, I can display it but I don't want to save those changes (since I'm trying to present data differently but keep the original values returned from db).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The whole point of something like `DropDownListFor`, whether native or Kendo's version, is to create an input that's bound to a particular property. Without the context of the property, there's no way for it know what the input should be named. However, check the definition in the Kendo docs. There might be an overload that allows you to pass both the property to bind to and the value you want applied as a separate param. If not, then you'll need to set it on your entity or view model server-side before you send it to the view.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This was the answer I was looking for!